# Could not insert new action connection Error

Tags: iphone, xcode

I get this error, when try to create new action for UIButton by dragging blue arrow from UIButton to my header file (you know, this new feature of XCode 4...)

When I create action in code by myself and connect it in old way, simply by dragging from button to File's Owner, it's works well

Here's screenshot:
[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Create an `IBAction` in the code and then connect it to the story board. It is strange but will save you from restarting your computer just to add few `IBActions`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Make sure your .m file exists in the project and on disk. Make sure it is correct with an `@implementaiton`-`@end` block. Open it in Xcode, close it, if the error persist, restart Xcode.

Xcode is trying to write to `EditPUViewController.m` (in the `dealloc` method etc.) but could not find it.

Also, it always helps to hard-clean the project with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

Comment: Problem solved only after restarting of comp. But thanks a lot!!

Comment: Make sure the source file .m is listed in the 
Build Phases -> Compile Sources list.

Answer (score 21):

Try this:

Open Organizer then Project Tab.

Clear the "Derived Data". Xcode should re-index your project then and code sense should work. At least worked for me.

Comment: +1 because this helped me. Could you please explain though what happens in the process? :)

Comment: if didn't work restart Xcode after do @Rusy's procedure

Answer (score 8):

I had a comparable problem when trying to connect an action. To solve it I manually added the IBAction and then XCode allowed me to connect from the button to the code.

Comment: I did the same thing with IBOutlet

Answer (score 7):

Go to Xcode -> preferences -> location tab -> derived data -> clear derived dat.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue myself but none of the methods presented here worked for me. The error described in the question above occurred when I tried to create an `IBAction` in my view's header file (.h), whereas to my implementation file (.m) I couldn't even drag a line. (Xcode wouldn't even show this little popup where you can name your action.)

After trying for hours I figured that the reason why I couldn't create the `IBAction` was because I had removed the very last line from my .m file. **Xcode automatically adds an extra empty line after the `@end` delimiter** when you create a new Objective-C file.

Don't ask me why - but **if you remove that line Xcode doesn't let you create any actions or outlets**. (This is obviously an Xcode bug.)

[image: Wrong]

[image: Right]

Comment: I had the extra line already. I added another one and then it worked. Weird bugs lol

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that .m file was moved inside en.lproj folder.

Just delete (reference only) the .m file from the Xcode and moved .m out of the en.lproj. Add it again.Don't worry, you will get all your connections back.

It will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across this problem. I soon realized that the cause had been my own doing.
I had previously disabled XCode indexing (which used to take forever & eat up my RAM), using the below code in a terminal window:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexDisable 1
```

To revert XCode to its default state, i used the following line in a terminal window:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexDisable 0
```

Voila! All's well again..

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. Restarting Xcode did not fix it for me (I didn't want to reboot). The file was also not in the en.lproj folder (nor in the usual project folder after I deleted it from within Xcode). The fix for me was to re-create the file with a different name (Using different case in the filename alone was not enough to fix it... must be a different name entirely).

Comment: I made simply manual connection like in previous versions of xCode. Also helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when I created a class, deleted it and then created a new one with the same name. The workaround was not to reuse the name of the deleted class, but use a new one. Thus, I'd say it's a bug on the XCode side.

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the newly created class (don’t delete it, just remove link and then re-add it);
- Save Xib file;
- Restart Xcode;
- You may want to delete Derived Data as well if it does still not work.

This seems because of XCode is missing reference or need to refresh manually.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, removing the reference of the nib(.xib) and adding it again solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had by accident selected the arm64 build. When compiling I got an error but I did not notice that since I was working with the UI trying to connect an action.

The error however was exactly the same. After changing to another architecture so the project compiled I could connect the action by holding the ctrl button as usual.

Answer (score 0):

user2175983 and AstroCB answer's worked well for me:

1. Just delete all Derived data by running this command line in a terminal:

   rm -frd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
2. Restart Xcode

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the reference to the file in the Xcode project and then re-added the file back to project from the finder...

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 9 I had the same error after moving .m files in project from one directory to another. Deleting references to .m files and add them again did solve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I found the ANSWER. When you create a new file (Objective C files) for each view controller, you must check by clicking the box, next to your project name. So that your project includes this file. Otherwise, this error will persist, because your project hasn't connected to the file even though it created it.