# I did not use refactor to change a class' name in iOS/Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I did a newbie thing renamed my one of my classes with just a double-click and rename. I know that this is the completely incorrect way of doing this but now I'm experiencing what seems to be a simple problem. When trying to connect a new "IBAction" or "IBOutlet" I get this error message:

> Could not insert new action connection: Could not insert source code into document at URL file://localhost/Users/Myuser/file/filename/projectname/SGLoginHomeViewController.m because it does not contain a class interface for the class named SGLoginHomeViewController

I'm sure this can be easily fixed, but how?

P.S. I changed the prefix to RG instead of SG, and then back to SG.  I made changes in the following locations:  the @interface in the .h, the @implementation in the .m, and the file name in the left side-view of Xcode under the Project folder drop-down.

Comment: Have you changed class name for your XIB ? and connected view with new ?

Comment: Yes I did that. And I'm glad that you mentioned that because that is another place that I temporarily changed the prefix.

Comment: Something is wrong with your .m file. Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176364/could-not-insert-new-action-connection-error and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996023/could-not-insert-new-outlet-connection-error

Comment: oh wow. that was the problem haha, I thought I had messed up my sources or something. thank you @ßhargavi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply delete the class references and remove the class from it's source folder location